# Wrapping a reoccuring collection of elements in a div

Tags: javascript, html

This is kind of a two part question - I have an HTML page where I need to take reoccurring groups of elements such as:

```
<h2>1</h2>
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
<h2>2</h2>
<p>fizz</p>
```

and wrap them individually with divs on each heading:

```
<div>
  <h2>1</h2>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>2</h2>
  <p>fizz</p>
</div>
```

I know about getting elements by tag name, but I can't work out how to take the group of elements and then replacing them.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: can you give expected output image??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.from()`, `.forEach()` loop to iterate `h2` elements collection, check if `.nextElementSibling` `.tagName` is `"P"` in `while` loop, if `true`, push elements to an array.

Use `.forEach()` on array of arrays of `p` elements, create `<div>` element, append `h2` at `index` of array to `div` element, loop each element of inner array, call `.appendChild()` with `p` element as parameter.

```js
var headers = document.querySelectorAll("h2");
var arr = [];

Array.from(headers).forEach(function(h2, index) {
  arr[index] = [];
  var curr = h2.nextElementSibling;
  while (curr.tagName === "P") {
    arr[index].push(curr);
    var next = curr.nextElementSibling;
    curr = next;
  }
});

arr.forEach(function(html, index) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(headers[index]);
  html.forEach(function(el) {
    div.appendChild(el)
  })
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<h2>1</h2>
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
<h2>2</h2>
<p>fizz</p>
```